# Slurm job array

Tags: slurm

It is fairly easy to submit an array job, e.g.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1

#SBATCH --array 1-10

module load python

python script.py
```

This will run `script.py` 10 times using separate array jobs.

How do I tell slurm that e.g. only 2 nodes are used for all jobs in the array?
I am aware on how to limit concurrently running jobs via something like `1-10%5`, but his is not what I am looking for.
Moreover `--nodes` seems to be applied to the individual jobs.